# Comparing a given subdomain with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this problem. FOr example I have this URL http://site-myname.testingsite.localhost/auth/register?r=, uwing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] I am able to get the value '***auth/register?r=***'. Now what I want to do is to check using **regex** and **preg_match** ***'/auth/register?r='*** or ***'/auth/register?r=anyvalue'*** so that if any user who will have query string 'r' with any value or null value will be under scope.

My initial solution is:

```
preg_match('#/auth/register\?r=^$#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Please help me! I'm stuck in this problem for an hour now and I don't want to waste time.. Answers will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Unclear. How is `auth/register?r=` related to a subdomain?

Comment: why not `$_GET['r']`?

Comment: Hi guys, its hard to explain but I have reasons why I am compelled to use regex instead of $_GET. I need to improve also my regex abilities. Hope my question will be answered. Thanks

Comment: What I am trying to do is to get the entire URL with the query string and not the query string only. Which is why I didn't use $_GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure that I follow the question, but it seems what you want is just

```
   ^/auth/register\?r=
```

if you're trying to capture the value of `r` perhaps…

```
  ^/auth/register\?r=([^;&]*)
```

Comment: ^ only matches the start of a string; you'd need to use $ to match the end (unless there's a literal `^` in your query string?)

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
preg_match('#/auth/register\?r=[^&]*#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

Comment: Excellent answer! This worked. But I chose to accept BRPocock's answer because its much simplier to understand. Thanks and cheers! I would like to vote up your answer but I cannot yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it validates for me:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$strRegex = '%/auth/register\?r=%';
if (preg_match($strRegex, $uri)) echo "matched";
else echo "not matched";
```